# Bootstrapping. Common emitter amplifier

Tags: amplifier, common-emitter, bootstrap

**How to properly choose bootstrap capacitor and resistor in the common-emitter amplifier circuit, if we know that the circuit should have a low-frequency 3dB point at 100 Hz?**

Here is the schematic. :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgERxG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

All the values, except Cb and Rb were calculated from the previous exercise.

Here is my efforts:

1) **Rb.**
The network is used to increase the input impeadance and bootstrapping resistor is connected in parallel with the emitter resistor. At signal frequencies (X\$_{C_b}\$, X\$_{C_1}\$ \$\approx\$ 0), the impedance looking into the input is:

$$ R_{in} = \beta R_e || (R_{b_{eq}} + R_1||R_2),    (1) $$

where

$$ R_{b_{eq}} = \frac{R_b}{1 - (R_1||R_2||R_e)/(r_e+R_1||R_2||R_e)} \approx  20 R_b \space \space 
(\text{taking re = 50 Ohms for Ic = 0.5 mA  in this case}).       (2) $$
is the equivalent bootstrap resistance, considering feedback.

To maximize the input impedance from Eq. (1), we should have 
$$ \beta R_e \approx (R_{b_{eq}} + R_1||R_2)\approx R_{b_{eq}},     (3) $$

which yields:
 $$ R_b \approx \frac{\beta R_e}{20} \approx 5 \space kOhm. $$.

So far so good.

2) Now in order to get the capacitor value, we need to use the information about 3dB point at 100 Hz.

This is my equivalent scheme for high-frequencies:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXCCaX.png)</sup>

In order for feedback to work properly, it should have the same cut-off point. So I assume we can just look from the emitter output back towards \$ C_b \$ and \$ R_b \$ and see a low-pass filter formed by \$ C_b \$ and \$ R_1||R_2 \$, which yields \$ C_b = 1.6 \space \mu  F\$.

**1) Are these considerations correct (for Rb and Cb)?**

**2) Is there something else one has to take into account choosing the values?**

**3) Does introduction of the bootstrap affects high-frequency performance of this circuit in any way?**

Comment: 1) looks reasonable 2) LF boost amplitude 1dB on input shifts f-3db lower to ~ 50Hz on my SIM 3) no  : what gain do you get 24?  what -3dB f ? 50 Hz?  Do you care about Zin(f)? in general...

Comment: Yes , the gain is about 24 and -3dBm is at 51 Hz.  Why is the gain increased from 15 (for no bootstraping case)? I did not notice that before.

Comment: @Serhii Did you account for loading on the input?

Comment: @Serhii The bootstrap itself is almost never a problem with frequency response. (I never build a simple CE BJT amplifier -- I always use bootstrapping, as it isn't worth doing unless you add bootstrapping.) Have you done the Laplace KCL equations for your circuit to develop the transfer function?

Comment: @jonk Actually I just rerun the simulation and I realised that high-f effect was due to the wrong scaling on the Vout(f) plot. Now I see both -3dB points at 3.3 MHz (transistor is 2N2222A). I did not do Laplace KLC for any circuit up to now :D. I will read about it and try to apply. I would be very appreciate if you could show me it in an answer.

Comment: For intuition, Collector / Emitter output impedance is a lot higher than the voltage ratio  so the feedback current has a slight peak in the transfer functions during the breakpoint for Vbe, Vb, Ve and Vc due to the AC current and impedance ratio changes. this lowers your 1st estimate of 100Hz.

Comment: @Serhii Glad you worked out the wrong scaling issue. Verbal Kint would probably do a better "low entropy" version of the transfer function, though I have read some of Dr. Middlebrook stuff in the past, so I'm not completely ignorant. I'm just not as skilled as Kint at these things. (This is about presenting the transfer function in better fashion, not working it out.) Meanwhile, I'll post up the transfer function in a way that may help out. I don't do simulations until I've worked out the theory -- I use simulation to demonstrate theory works and I don't use simulation to guess at the theory.

Comment: Kint & @jonk are far better at the rigours of math, but having done enough in the past, it becomes intuitive for me, so it's quicker for me and more informative to look at a 6 point graph simulation.http://tinyurl.com/rx8botb  Its like a 12 point EKG I had last week with echo cargiogram and gamma ray images.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Hmm. Did you get the transesophageal echocardiogram? Or just the transthoracic one?